# How to hook eval function in node.js

Tags: patching, function-hooking, javascript, hooking

As the `eval()` function of JavaScript is an evil, I want to hook or monkey-patch `eval()` function of JavaScript in node.js. I want to intercept all arguments passed in `eval()` function. Please guide me how to hook or monkey patch `eval()` function.